# Using expressions in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am new in iReport and using iReport 5.6.0 I was trying to show a text based on a condition. Suppose, I have two variables name `Cr` and `Dr`. And I want to show a text `Net Profit` when `Cr>Dr` and `Net Loss` when `Dr>Cr`. I was trying something like this.

> ($V{Dr_total}.compareTo($V{Cr_total} )? "Net Profit": "Net Loss" )

And any details tutorial about Using User Defined Expression in iReport would be very much helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. In Print When Expression I used something like this. The text is only showing when this condition is fulfilling.

> $V{Dr_total}.intValue()<= $V{Cr_total}.intValue() ? Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE